# How to reset React hook state with setTimeout in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have a simple component that copies a link to the clipboard, and would like to swap the link icon with a checkmark. I have the logic setup to do so, but having an issue getting the state reset after 3 seconds to reset the button back to the link icon. How can I properly setup my `useEffect` and state hook to set and then reset the state for showing/hiding the link to checkmark and back again?

```
const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState('');
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
const copyToClipBoard = async copyHeader => {
try {
  await navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyHeader);
    setCopySuccess('Copied!');
  } catch (err) {
    setCopySuccess('Failed to copy!');
  }
};

<Button>
    {copySuccess ? (
       <Icon name="success" />
    ):(
     <Icon
        name="linked"
        onClick={() => copyToClipBoard(url)}
     />
    )}
</Button>
```

I was trying a `useEffect` like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setVisible(false);
    }, 3000);
 });
```

but not sure how to use the `setVisible` state and timeout, to swap the icon back to the link to let users know they can copy it again.

Comment: Try including `copySuccess` as a dependency in the `useEffect` dependency array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive the visible state from `copySuccess` state, try adding it to `useEffect` dep array:

```
const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState("");
const copyToClipBoard = async (copyHeader) => {
  try {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyHeader);
    setCopySuccess("Copied!");
  } catch (err) {
    setCopySuccess("Failed to copy!");
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (copySuccess !== "") {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCopySuccess("");
    }, 3000);
  }
}, [copySuccess]);

<Button>
  {copySuccess ? (
    <Icon name="success" />
  ) : (
    <Icon name="linked" onClick={() => copyToClipBoard(url)} />
  )}
</Button>;
```

See similar logic in codesandbox example:

```
function Component() {
  const [copyIsAvailable, setCopyIsAvailable] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCopyIsAvailable(true);
    }, 1000);
  }, [copyIsAvailable]);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => setCopyIsAvailable(false)}>
      {copyIsAvailable ? "copy" : "copied"}
    </button>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-65373145-setTimeout]

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you changing the async function to update `visible`.
Then change thee button tag:

```
<Button>
    {visible 
      ? <Icon name="success" />
      : <Icon
         name="linked"
         onClick={() => copyToClipBoard(url)}
        />
    }
</Button>
```